# Is there a straightforward way to install Debian with Wifi?

Tags: debian, wifi, debian-installer

I understand that we live in a post-apocalyptic hellscape where people own the math behind wifi and software freedom is important and yatta yatta yatta yatta. Debian values software freedom and doesn't love distributing nonfree versions of its distro. I appreciate that.

But that doesn't change the fact that I need wifi, and I need it out the box. I don't like sitting next to my router for long periods of time. It's not in a place with a chair and desk. It hurts my back. Please don't make me do it.

Is there a way to install Debian with Wifi?

Comment: If you provide the hardware details someone might even be able to tell you if it'll work with the unofficial ISO or other firmware add-in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You means: having a Debian installation ISO containing some non-free firmware (eg. those for your wifi hardware)

-> https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/

Comment: Thanks. I thought this existed but couldn't seem to find it.